# What online computer language interpreters are available, so I can practice programming from my iPhone?

Tags: webapp-rec

I want to play with interpreted code on my iPhone without jailbreaking. I'm familiar with  [tryruby](http://tryruby.org/) for ruby.  Are there any other online interpreters out there that I can use.

Comment: belongs on StackOveflow, doesn't it? 
edit: ah, ok, it's about *online* interpreters...

Comment: I've made this a community wiki because multiple answers are applicable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Taken from [Is there a web application that can replace an IDE like Eclipse?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/532/is-there-a-web-application-that-can-replace-an-ide-like-eclipse)

You will want to check out http://ideone.com/ 
It is a mini IDE and debugging tool mainly used as a clipboard.

Example The following counts from 1 to 10

```
class ForDemo {
     public static void main(String[] args){
          for(int i=1; i<11; i++){
               System.out.println("Count is: " + i)
          }
     }
}
```

Selecting Java in the side bar of *ideone* will give us

```
Main.java:4: ';' expected
               System.out.println("Count is: " + i)
                                                   ^
1 error
```

Then fixing that gives us the following shortlink http://ideone.com/gGqZy which you can share

I posted the output below

```
# 1:   hide   edit   3 seconds ago
result: success      time: 0.03s    memory: 213312 kB     returned value: 0

input: no
output:
Count is: 1
Count is: 2
Count is: 3
Count is: 4
Count is: 5
Count is: 6
Count is: 7
Count is: 8
Count is: 9
Count is: 10
```

Comment: Very useful answer indeed. I missed webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/532/… despite reviewing most of the questions. I think I would let this question stand though, because I want a sense of other interpreted options that might be out there and some perhaps even more adaptable to the small browser. Thank you very much.

Comment: I picked this answer, because although ideone's interface was a bit awkward on the iPhone, it was still workable (with a lot of pinch and spread) and nothing else comes close in language choice. I wish I could select all these answers. My iPhone will be a friendlier place.

Answer (score 6):

For html / css / javascript, try http://jsfiddle.net/ .  It also acts as a pastebin allowing url sharing and editing.

Comment: Nice! A web-app for web-apps.

Answer (score 4):

[tryhaskell.org](http://tryhaskell.org/) if you are interested in functional programming

Comment: I can't believe I missed this. I loo..oove Haskell. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Why go to multiple sites?  Just head on over to the [Lord of the REPLs](http://lotrepls.appspot.com/)!

Currently it supports

- beanshell
- clojure
- groovy
- javascript
- python
- ruby
- scala
- scheme

Comment: I love the minimalist command line interface. Would be my fave if it had ghci.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to try Javascript/HTML, w3schools.com has a "Tryit Editor". It's used for tutorial purpose, but you can code and test anything with it online.

Link : http://w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_text

Comment: This has a nice, simple interface. Very usable. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[codepad](http://codepad.org/) is an online interpreter that supports several different languages.  It also generates a URL for your snippets, so you can share them and collaborate.

Comment: Good, tried it, very nice!

Comment: Slightly superior to ideone in its simplicity of interface and similar in its language diversity.

Answer (score 2):

The [Groovy Web Console](http://groovyconsole.appspot.com/) is a great way to try out Groovy code.  It uses the [CodeMirror](http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/codemirror/) in-browser code editor and allows you to publish/share scripts if you wish.

Comment: Thanks. This isn't in my repertoire, but I'll take a look.

Answer (score 2):

Ideon is a great answer, but you can also find a large number of repls here http://joel.franusic.com/Online-REPs-and-REPLs

Comment: This is a great reference resource!

Answer (score 2):

There's http://kodingen.com .  It may be too complicated to use on a small iPhone screen though.

Comment: Interesting. This will take some exploring.

Answer (score 1):

[Skulpt](http://www.skulpt.org/) is an entirely in-browser implementation of Python.  Not complete, but handy.

Comment: Again, the simplicity of the interface is a plus. Thank you.

Comment: That it's all implemented in javascript in the browser is a big plus.

Answer (score 0):

[Simply Scala](http://www.simplyscala.com) for Scala programming language.

Answer (score 0):

[Forth](http://forthfreak.net/jsforth80x25.html) here is.

Comment: (-; (-: (-; OK.