# What are the existing services for sharing code?

Tags: pastebin, file-sharing

I was wondering what are the existing service for sharing code. The only one I know is http://pastebin.ca/

What are the other alternative and what feature do they have ?

Comment: Perhaps you could clarify:  are you looking for options for sharing projects and incorporating source control, or are you looking for options for sharing code snippets as a pastebin?  I seem to have interpreted the question differently than others.

Comment: [ohloh](https://www.ohloh.net/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are 4 that I know of:

1. http://bitbucket.org/ (for Mercurial Version Control)
2. http://github.com/ (for Git Version Control)
3. http://www.codeplex.com/
4. http://sourceforge.net/

The big difference in features are that options 1 and 2 seamlessly integrate version control and allow you to have public and private projects.  So you will be able to work with others on code without the whole world seeing it.

Options 3 and 4 allow version control but I am not sure how tightly integrated they are with certain version control systems.  Also, my understanding is that you can't keep projects private in those 2 systems.

In general the Ruby community used github, the python community uses bitbucket, microsoft runs codeplex, and sourceforge is all about open source.  Though I believe you can use any language with any of them.

For code snippets I think http://ideone.com/, http://friendpaste.com/, and http://jsfiddle.net/ are good. JSFiddle is especially awesome for editing and sharing Javascript.

Comment: github also have something called [gist](http://gist.github.com/) to share smaller pieces of code. It's like pastebin, but with version control.

Answer (score 2):

If you literally just want duplicate pastbin functionality I use [Friend Paste](http://friendpaste.com). It allows you go comment on lines of code, edit friend's code, and even set a password that people have to enter to view it.

Answer (score 2):

[Forrst](http://forrst.com/) allows you to share code (and screenshots/links) and discuss them, currently in beta and invite-only but due to open up soon.

Here's an example post:
[Forrst screeny http://cl.ly/1aVE/Screen_shot_2010-07-08_at_16.38.25.png](http://cl.ly/1aVE/Screen_shot_2010-07-08_at_16.38.25.png)

Answer (score 1):

See [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1953/what-online-computer-language-interpreters-are-available-so-i-can-practice-progr/) that also brings in executing the code.  Answers regarding [IDEOne](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1953/what-online-computer-language-interpreters-are-available-so-i-can-practice-progr/1961#1961) and [JSFiddle](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1953/what-online-computer-language-interpreters-are-available-so-i-can-practice-progr/1970#1970) both offer pastebin functionality.  Some of the others may as well.

Answer (score 1):

For sharing, writing simple JS code http://www.jsbin.com/ is pretty cool!!

Answer (score 1):

I use [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) all the time for javascript prototyping or code snippet sharing.

Answer (score 0):

Assembla is a good one.  http://www.assembla.com  It offers Git and SVN source code control, tickets, private/public options, user management, web viewing, etc.  Prices start at free and move upwards from there. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share between fewer than ten people, then take a look at Fisheye: http://www.atlassian.com/software/fisheye/ - it's $10.

It hooks into a subversion repository, so you can see changesets of people's checkins. Another application which works well with Fisheye is Crucible, http://www.atlassian.com/software/crucible/ which works for code reviews.

Answer (score 0):

http://collabedit.com

Features Include:

- Real time editing
- Syntax highlighting
- Sidebar Chat
- History

Answer (score 0):

This question was asked on stackoverflow for c#/.NET code: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078045/is-there-a-public-site-to-make-and-share-live-examples-of-c-net-code/

A good answer is CodeRun:

http://coderun.com/ide/

Answer (score 0):

Try [Liveweave](http://liveweave.com) for HTML5, CSS3 & JS coding. It is awesome!